# Appending single quote and comma to a string in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have a string like 'ABC,DEF,GHI'. I want to append single quotes and comma and my result should be like this 'ABC','DEF','GHI'

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: it seems that you have to `REPLACE` the `,` with `','`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you think that can help you get around the problem of using a string like 'ABC,DEF,GHI' in an `IN` condition, think again; it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `REPLACE()` function. You also need to add single quotes at the beginning and the end of the string (if they don't exist already - in my solution below I assume they don't), and you must be careful with the single-quote literal since it also has a special meaning in strings.

Something like this should work:

```
with inputs ( str ) as ( select 'ABC,DEF,GHI' from dual )
  --  end of test data (not part of the solution); SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select str as old_str, '''' || replace(str, ',', ''',''') || '''' as new_str
from   inputs
;

OLD_STR       NEW_STR
-----------   -----------------
ABC,DEF,GHI   'ABC','DEF','GHI'
```